# Correlation coefficient different from zero as Null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

According to Wikipedia:

> In inferential statistics, the term "null hypothesis" usually refers
>   to a general statement or default position that there is no
>   relationship between two measured phenomena, or no association among
>   groups.
>   ...
>   The statement that is hoped or expected to be true instead of the null hypothesis is the alternative hypothesis

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis

In my situation, the default position is that there is a correlation between two variables, and the statement that is hoped to be true is that there is no correlation (if some other variable is controlled for).

Questions:

1) Can I state the null hypothesis as "correlation is different from zero", and the alternate hypothesis as "correlation is equal to zero"?

2) Assuming I can do that, then consider situation when I obtain a correlation coefficient of say 0.05 with p-value 0.8. Would it be right to say the null hypothesis is rejected because the correlation coefficient is not different from zero with p-value of 0.8?

Comment: Would it not be more informative to present a confidence interval for $\rho$?

Comment: The idea was to apply the standard framework of hypothesis testing, where you have the null hypothesis and the alternate hypothesis. Or perhaps I am not understanding your comment?

Comment: I was suggesting a procedure which might answer your (unstated) scientific question better.

Comment: "Correlation different from zero" is useless as a hypothesis: it does not permit one to obtain any observable information about correlation that wouldn't already be known in the absence of that assumption.  Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31 and search our site for [TOST](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=TOST).